# Coproduct of groups explanation

Tags: group-theory, category-theory

Could someone please explain the following?
"Let $G=\prod G_{i}$ be a direct product of groups. Then each $G_j$ admits an injective homomorphism into the product, on the j-th component, namely the map $\lambda_j:G_j \to \prod G_i$ such that for x in $G_j$, the i-th component of $\lambda_j(x)$ is the is the unit element of $G_i$ if $i \neq j$, and is equal to x itself if $i=j$. This embedding will be called the canonical one. But we still dont have a coproduct of the family, because the factors commute with each other."

Comment: can you perhaps give the precise quote, with sufficient information to really discern what is going on?

Comment: I just checked in Lang, he doesn't say that there is no coproduct in the category of groups, but he says that the product of groups is not the coproduct.

Comment: Thanks guys, sorry i edited the question.

Answer (score 2):

There is a coproduct in the category of groups, namely the free product. Perhaps you mean the category of finite groups, which does not have a coproduct. Lang says that the coproduct in the category of groups is not the product; in any abelian category finite products coincide with finite coproducts, e.g., in the category of abelian groups.

Comment: Thanks Dietrich. I was also looking for an explanation as to how the coproduct's factors commute and why this isnt the case for the product.

Comment: @37edude73 No, this is the contrary: in $G \times H$, the elements of $G$ and the elements of $H$ commute ($(g,e_H) \cdot (e_G, h) = (g,h) = (e_G, h) \cdot (g, e_H)$), ; whereas in $G * H$ (the free product = coproduct), they do not.